# Trying to get a value from an address is giving me an access violation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, masm

(Windows 7 x64)

I stored some value in memory and I created a function to return that address. But when I try to get the value, it gives me

```
First-chance exception at 0x000000013fbc1b2b in Testing.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000003fbca000.
Unhandled exception at 0x000000013fbc1b2b in Testing.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000003fbca000.
The program '[2528] Testing.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
```

C++:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" unsigned long getMemoryAddress();
extern "C" unsigned long getValue(unsigned long address);

int main() {
    unsigned long address = getMemoryAddress();
    unsigned long value = getValue(address);

    std::cout << "Address: " << address << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value: " << value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And from Assembly

```
    .data
    memory db 15

.code

    getMemoryAddress proc
        lea rax, memory ; Get address to return
        ret
    getMemoryAddress endp

    getValue proc
        mov rax, [rcx] ; Get value from address
        ret
    getValue endp

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unsigned long is 32-bit in MSVC, so can't hold an address. Use uintptr_t which is guaranteed to be the same size as a pointer.